# PowerShell Start-Process cmdlet when ArgumentList is empty

Tags: powershell, process, arguments

I've simplified my situation as much as possible. I have a PowerShell script that programmatically starts a process with the *"Run as administrator"* option using the [Start-Process](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) cmdlet:

```powershell
param
(
    # Arguments to pass to the process, if any
    [string[]] $ArgList
)

if($ArgList)
{
    Start-Process -FilePath notepad.exe -ArgumentList $ArgList -Verb RunAs
}
else
{
    Start-Process -FilePath notepad.exe -Verb RunAs
}
```

Since `ArgumentList` cannot be NULL nor empty, I had to add the `if-else` to avoid a *ParameterArgumentValidationError* error.

Everything works as expected with no problem, but I was just wondering if there's a more elegant (but still simple) way to accomplish that without using the `if-else` blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way using the splat operator `@` (see Richard answerd) and maybe using a format string with a condition. However, I think the `If-else` Statement is the **most readable and clear way** to do this and I wouldn't try to simplify it.

Comment: I agree, it's good to know about the solution with the splat operator, but the original code looks more readable and it's probably what I'm going to use.

Comment: Well, I also miss something like a '$variable ? then : else' statement.

Comment: That would be cool, but I don't think PowerShell supports the ternary operator

Comment: FYI [Ternary operator in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341998/ternary-operator-in-powershell)

Comment: When more than one argument must be manipulated this way (through if..else.. structures) the splat operator becomes very handy! :)

Comment: @ZoltanHernyak true!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ["splat" operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) to dynamically add parameters.

Define a hash with keys for parameter names. And then pass that to the cmdlet:

```
$extras = @{}
if (condition) { $extras["ArgumentList"] = whatever }

Start-Process -FilePath = "notepad.exe" @extras
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the splat operator. That's not complicated at all but I think the original code is more readable so I'll probably keep my _if-else_ blocks. Answer upvoted though.

Comment: @mguassa Your solution might look cleaner, but it is NOT a good idea in general, as it involves duplication of code and maintaining duplicate pieces of code. This answer - is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Powershell 7 and do not have this problem, I run
`Start-Process -ArgumentList $args`
in a function where `$args` is sometimes null and it works fine.

However, my script does not run on Windows PowerShell.

It looks like Powershell 7 no longer requires you to have the if-else statement here.