# Ternary operator in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

From what I know, PowerShell doesn't seem to have a built-in expression for the so-called [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

For example, in the C language, which supports the ternary operator, I could write something like:

```
<condition> ? <condition-is-true> : <condition-is-false>;
```

If that doesn't really exist in PowerShell, what would be the best way (i.e. easy to read and to maintain) to accomplish the same result?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShellTraps/tree/master/Basic/Missing-ternary-operator . If this is what you are looking for I can make it an answer.

Comment: It's a *conditional* operator or ternary *if*. It's not "the ternary operator" since all that means is a operator (*any* operator) that takes three arguments.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's technically true, but it's often called ternary operator. _"Since this operator is often the only existing ternary operator in the language, it is sometimes simply referred to as "the ternary operator". In some languages, this operator is referred to as "the conditional operator."_ [Ternary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

Comment: Visual basic does not have a true ternary operator but considers the IF and IFF to be functionally equivelent.

Comment: @Matt That's incorrect. The `IIF` *function* will always evaluate both operands. The `If` statement will not - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220411/vb-net-iif-both-sides-are-evaluated-what-situations-should-i-watch-ou (newer VB.NET versions added a ternary expression: `If (x, y, z)`)

Comment: I feel like powershell should allow you to use whatever .NET language you want. Then there won't be missing operator questions, because they'll all be there.

Comment: The ternary operator was added to native PowerShell in version 7. Added an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 511):

```
$result = If ($condition) {"true"} Else {"false"}
```

For use in or as an expression, not just an assignment, wrap it in `$()`, thus:

```
write-host  $(If ($condition) {"true"} Else {"false"})
```

Comment: That works on the right side of an equals, but not quite as you'd expect a ternary operator - these fail: *"a" + If ($condition) {"true"} Else {"false"}* and *"a" + (If ($condition) {"true"} Else {"false"})*

This works (I'm not yet sure why): *"a" + $(If ($condition) {"true"} Else {"false"})*

Comment: @Lamarth - That works because the `$()` wrapper forces evaluation of the statement as an expression, thus returning either the true value of the false value, much like a ternary operator would be expected to. This is the closest you'll get in PowerShell AFAIK.

Comment: Unlike some of the other "non function" answers, this will *also* ensure that only one branch is executed.

Comment: "Everything else is incidental complexity and thus to be avoided." - opinion, not fact.

Comment: "Everything else is incidental complexity and thus to be avoided." - Great life advice.

Comment: This approach fails if your "true" value evaluates to an empty collection, where it will get coerced to null.

Answer (score 180):

Powershell 7, released 2020, introduced a [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7.3#using-the-ternary-operator-syntax):

```
$message = (Test-Path $path) ? "Path exists" : "Path not found"
```

Answer (score 85):

The closest PowerShell construct I've been able to come up with to emulate that is:

```
@({'condition is false'},{'condition is true'})[$condition]
```

Comment: `({true}, {false})[!$condition]` is slightly better (perhaps): a) traditional order of true and false parts; b) `$condition` does not have to be just 0 or 1 or $false, $true. The operator `!` converts it as needed. I.e. `$condition` can be, say, 42: !42 ~ $false ~ 0 ~ first expression.

Comment: Not quite identical, @RomanKuzmin. mjolinor's example returns a string. But the same string values from his example plugged into your expression returns a script block. :-(

Comment: By `{true}` and `{false}` I mean `<true expression>` and `<false expression>`, not script blocks. Sorry for being not accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @RomanKuzmin--now I see the value in your suggestion.

Comment: As per blog post from 2102 - http://www.kongsli.net/2012/02/23/powershell-another-alternative-to-ternary-operator/

Comment: This will force eager-evaluation of left and right options: this is much different from a proper ternary operation.

Comment: Or `('condition is false','condition is true')[$condition]`

Comment: Or `[[bool]$condition]` for objects.

Comment: The comments here confused me, while my goal was close. Notice no script block. Here's an obvious sample that can be used: `$didUserChooseYes = ($true, $false)[!($choice -eq 'Y')]`

Comment: @AlexKwitny Maybe your example is just for demonstration purposes, but it's not a great example. It's a really overwrought way of writing: `$didUserChooseYes = $choice -eq 'Y'`

Comment: @JLRishe, yes it is a practical demonstration. The first comment combined with the answer is confusing when you're trying to get a working product. Many people working with PowerShell are not developers, they're SysAdmins and pseudo code doesn't translate to raw syntax they can plug/play.

Comment: @AlexKwitny Ok, it's just not really an example of a case where you would want to use this kind of thing. I think a better real-world example would be something like: `@('Not old enough to drive', 'Old enough to drive')[$age -ge 17]`

Comment: This is super useful for testing results like this `({true}, {false})[!$?]`. However, I was not able to get it to work with: `({'ok'}, {Write-Host -fore red 'fail!'})[!$?]`. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 34):

Try powershell's **switch** statement as an alternative, especially for variable assignment - multiple lines, but readable.

Example,

```
$WinVer = switch ( Test-Path -Path "$Env:windir\SysWOW64" ) {
  $true    { "64-bit" }
  $false   { "32-bit" }
}
"This version of Windows is $WinVer"
```

Comment: This may be slightly more verbose, but there are significant benefits over many of the other answers. In particular, there are no dependencies on external code, nor on functions being copied/pasted into a script or module.

Answer (score 28):

Per this [PowerShell blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/diy-ternary-operator/), you can create an alias to define a `?:` operator:

```
set-alias ?: Invoke-Ternary -Option AllScope -Description "PSCX filter alias"
filter Invoke-Ternary ([scriptblock]$decider, [scriptblock]$ifTrue, [scriptblock]$ifFalse) 
{
   if (&$decider) { 
      &$ifTrue
   } else { 
      &$ifFalse 
   }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$total = ($quantity * $price ) * (?:  {$quantity -le 10} {.9} {.75})
```

Comment: There does not appear to be a reason that 'decider' is a scriptblock. If `?:` is ever evaluated it will require the arguments are evaluated. Without a script block it would have a similar usage, eg. `(?: ($quantity -le 10) {.9} {.75})`

Comment: That is a cool feature but it can render your script as non-standard e.g. your script or portions of it may not port unless the alias definition is also ported with it. You are basically creating your own sub-language at this point. All of this can lead to increased cost of maintenance due to increased complexity and decreased readability.

Comment: @VanceMcCorkle Solid point. Custom terseness is worth its cost if useful often. But if the situation only occurs rarely, I'd stick with an "if" expression.

Answer (score 24):

As of PowerShell version 7, the ternary operator is built into PowerShell.

```
1 -gt 2 ? "Yes" : "No"
# Returns "No"

1 -gt 2 ? 'Yes' : $null
# Get a $null response for false-y return value
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to replace, for example, "No" statement with "null" or something?

Comment: @RuslanKorkin I just updated the answer with an example. You can use `$null`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/58271485/11635

Answer (score 23):

I too, looked for a better answer, and while the solution in Edward's post is "ok", I came up with a far more natural [solution in this blog post](http://fearthecowboy.com/powershell/2015/12/11/PowerShell-A-Better-Ternary/)

Short and sweet:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:   Invoke-Assignment
# Alias:  =
# Author: Garrett Serack (@FearTheCowboy)
# Desc:   Enables expressions like the C# operators: 
#         Ternary: 
#             <condition> ? <trueresult> : <falseresult> 
#             e.g. 
#                status = (age > 50) ? "old" : "young";
#         Null-Coalescing 
#             <value> ?? <value-if-value-is-null>
#             e.g.
#                name = GetName() ?? "No Name";
#             
# Ternary Usage:  
#         $status == ($age > 50) ? "old" : "young"
#
# Null Coalescing Usage:
#         $name = (get-name) ? "No Name" 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# returns the evaluated value of the parameter passed in, 
# executing it, if it is a scriptblock   
function eval($item) {
    if( $item -ne $null ) {
        if( $item -is "ScriptBlock" ) {
            return & $item
        }
        return $item
    }
    return $null
}

# an extended assignment function; implements logic for Ternarys and Null-Coalescing expressions
function Invoke-Assignment {
    if( $args ) {
        # ternary
        if ($p = [array]::IndexOf($args,'?' )+1) {
            if (eval($args[0])) {
                return eval($args[$p])
            } 
            return eval($args[([array]::IndexOf($args,':',$p))+1]) 
        }

        # null-coalescing
        if ($p = ([array]::IndexOf($args,'??',$p)+1)) {
            if ($result = eval($args[0])) {
                return $result
            } 
            return eval($args[$p])
        } 

        # neither ternary or null-coalescing, just a value  
        return eval($args[0])
    }
    return $null
}

# alias the function to the equals sign (which doesn't impede the normal use of = )
set-alias = Invoke-Assignment -Option AllScope -Description "FearTheCowboy's Invoke-Assignment."
```

Which makes it easy to do stuff like (more examples in blog post):

```
$message == ($age > 50) ? "Old Man" :"Young Dude"
```

Comment: this is pretty awesome. I just don't like using `=` as the alias, because `==` is used in C# and a lot of other languages for equality checking. Having some experience in C# is pretty common among powershellers and that makes the resulting code a bit confusing. `:` would possibly be a better alias. Using it in conjuction with variable assignment `=:` might remind someone of the assignment used in Pascal, but does not have any immediate equivalent (that I know of) in VB.NET nor C#.

Comment: You could set this to whatever alias you'd like. `: ` or `~` or whatever floats your boat. :D

`set-alias : Invoke-Assignment -Option AllScope -Description "FearTheCowboy's Invoke-Assignment."`

# ternary
`$message =: ($age > 50) ? "Old Man" :"Young Dude" `

# null coalescing
`$message =: $foo ?? "foo was empty"`
`

Comment: I know, and I did, I was just commenting why I would use another alias.

Answer (score 10):

Since a ternary operator is usually used when assigning value, it should return a value. This is the way that can work:

```
$var=@("value if false","value if true")[[byte](condition)]
```

Stupid, but working. Also this construction can be used to quickly turn an int into another value, just add array elements and specify an expression that returns 0-based non-negative values.

Comment: This will force eager-evaluation of left and right options: this is much different from a proper ternary operation.

Answer (score 6):

I've recently improved (open PullRequest) the ternary conditional and null-coalescing operators in the PoweShell lib 'Pscx'
Pls have a look for my solution.

**My github topic branch:** [UtilityModule_Invoke-Operators](https://github.com/madmidi/Pscx/blob/UtilityModule_Invoke-Operators/Src/Pscx/Modules/Utility/Pscx.Utility.psm1)

#### Functions:

```
Invoke-Ternary
Invoke-TernaryAsPipe
Invoke-NullCoalescing
NullCoalescingAsPipe
```

#### Aliases

```
Set-Alias :?:   Pscx\Invoke-Ternary                     -Description "PSCX alias"
Set-Alias ?:    Pscx\Invoke-TernaryAsPipe               -Description "PSCX alias"
Set-Alias :??   Pscx\Invoke-NullCoalescing              -Description "PSCX alias"
Set-Alias ??    Pscx\Invoke-NullCoalescingAsPipe        -Description "PSCX alias"
```

#### Usage

```
<condition_expression> |?: <true_expression> <false_expression>

<variable_expression> |?? <alternate_expression>
```

As expression you can pass:
            $null, a literal, a variable, an 'external' expression ($b -eq 4) or a scriptblock {$b -eq 4}


If a variable in the variable expression is $null or not existing, the alternate expression is evaluated as output.

Answer (score 5):

Since I have used this many times already and didn't see it listed here, I'll add my piece :

`$var = @{$true="this is true";$false="this is false"}[1 -eq 1]`

ugliest of all !

[kinda source](http://www.kongsli.net/2012/02/23/powershell-another-alternative-to-ternary-operator/)

Comment: This will force eager-evaluation of left and right options: this is much different from a proper ternary operation.

Comment: @user2864740 that's because there is no proper ternary operation in PS. This is a synthetic variant.

Comment: @ViggoLundén Lack of a proper ternary operator does not reduce the correctness of the comment. This "synthetic variant" **has different behavior**.

Comment: You're right, and after re-reading your comment I understand how it can make a real difference. Thanks.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/a/31343093/11635

Answer (score 5):

PowerShell <strike>currently doesn't</strike> ***didn't*** have a native [Inline If](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIf) (or [ternary If](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)) but you could consider to use the custom cmdlet:

```
IIf <condition> <condition-is-true> <condition-is-false>
```

See: [PowerShell inline If (IIf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682507/powershell-inline-if-iif)

Comment: The linked post shows how to *create* an `IIf` function. However, there is no standard PowerShell `IIf` function/cmdlet.

Comment: @user2864740, So what? does that exclude the answer as a possible usable answer to the question: "*what would be the best way (i.e. easy to read and to maintain) to accomplish the same result?"* But that aside, the link refers to the IIf **question** (posted Sep 5 '14)  that is *very* similar to this (duplicate?). The rest of the answers in the linked question could also be seen as added value (and where the don't, it is mainly because they are duplicates).

Comment: A little bit of explanation goes a long way, and this is why *bare links* are discouraged, as is not closing for duplicates if there is no additional added information. Consider that a very small explanation would significantly increase the quality of such a *bare link* answer: "Powershell does not support a direct 'ternary' (^but see other answers). However, it is possible to write a function such as (^using this method, or see other answers) ..", but that's not *my* job to add. Answers can be amend / updated / etc. as applicable.

Comment: @user2864740, thanks for your feedback, I have made adjustments to the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking for a syntactically simple way to assign/return a string or numeric based on a boolean condition, you can use the multiplication operator like this:

```
"Condition is "+("true"*$condition)+("false"*!$condition)
(12.34*$condition)+(56.78*!$condition)
```

If you're only ever interested in the result when something is true, you can just omit the false part entirely (or vice versa), e.g. a simple scoring system:

```
$isTall = $true
$isDark = $false
$isHandsome = $true

$score = (2*$isTall)+(4*$isDark)+(10*$isHandsome)
"Score = $score"
# or
# "Score = $((2*$isTall)+(4*$isDark)+(10*$isHandsome))"
```

Note that the boolean value should not be the leading term in the multiplication, i.e. $condition*"true" etc. won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative custom function approach:

```
function Test-TernaryOperatorCondition {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true)]
        [bool]$ConditionResult
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [PSObject]$ValueIfTrue
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [ValidateSet(':')]
        [char]$Colon
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [PSObject]$ValueIfFalse
    )
    process {
        if ($ConditionResult) {
            $ValueIfTrue
        }
        else {
            $ValueIfFalse
        }
    }
}
set-alias -Name '???' -Value 'Test-TernaryOperatorCondition'
```

**Example**

```
1 -eq 1 |??? 'match' : 'nomatch'
1 -eq 2 |??? 'match' : 'nomatch'
```

**Differences Explained**

- Why is it 3 question marks instead of 1?

  - The `?` character is already an alias for `Where-Object`.
  - `??` is used in other languages as a null coalescing operator, and I wanted to avoid confusion.
- Why do we need the pipe before the command?

  - Since I'm utilising the pipeline to evaluate this, we still need this character to pipe the condition into our function
- What happens if I pass in an array?

  - We get a result for each value; i.e. `-2..2 |??? 'match' : 'nomatch'` gives: `match, match, nomatch, match, match` (i.e. since any non-zero int evaluates to `true`; whilst zero evaluates to `false`).
  - If you don't want that, convert the array to a bool; `([bool](-2..2)) |??? 'match' : 'nomatch'` (or simply: `[bool](-2..2) |??? 'match' : 'nomatch'`)

Answer (score 1):

@MikeSchinkel's answer is *almost* correct for Powershell 5.1 (which is realistically what most machines have on them, PS7 is not useful if it's not installed), but it fails in a specific edge-case:

Powershell will coerce the result of the `if` expression into `$null` if it is an empty collection.

For example,

```ps
$test = $(if($true) {@()})
$test.GetType()
```

fails with `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression`.

The correct trick is to use the aggressively-ugly powershell unary-comma operator.

```ps
$test = $(if($true) {,@()})
$test.GetType()
```

So, the full example code:

```ps
$trueValue = "foo","bar","baz","quux"
$falseValue = @()

($false, $true) | foreach-object {
  $condition = $_

  # meat is here
  $result = $(If ($condition) {,$trueValue} Else {,$falseValue}) 

  Write-Host "Length of result where condition is '$_': $($result.Count)"
}
```

yields

```txt
Length of result where condition is 'False': 0
Length of result where condition is 'True': 4
```

This appears to work for all possible cases of `$trueValue` and `$falseValue`, where they're an array, an object, or `$null`.

Same applies to switch-statements-as-expressions.

```ps
for($i = 0; $i -lt 7; $i++) {

  # meat is here
  $result = $(switch ($i) {
    0 {,$null}
    1 {,"example test"}
    2 {,@()}
    3 {,@('foo','bar','baz')}
    4 {,@{}}
    5 {,@{One=1; Two=2; Three=3}}
    6 {,[Collections.ArrayList]::new()}
    default {,"default"}
  })

  $resultDesc = if($result -eq $null) {
    '$null'
  } elseif($result -is [Collections.IEnumerable]) {
    #note: measure-object for hashtables always returns count of 1
    "[$($result.GetType())] with $(($result | measure-object).Count) members: $result"
  } else { 
    "[$($result.GetType())]: $result"
  }

  "$i = $resultDesc"
}
```

yields

```txt
0 = $null
1 = [string] with 1 members: example test
2 = [System.Object[]] with 0 members:
3 = [System.Object[]] with 3 members: foo bar baz
4 = [hashtable] with 1 members: System.Collections.Hashtable
5 = [hashtable] with 1 members: System.Collections.Hashtable
6 = [System.Collections.ArrayList] with 0 members:
```

So, the general rule:

`if` and `switch` can be used for expressions!  It's great!  But, you have to wrap them in `$()` and prepend all return values with `,` to prevent weird edge-cases in Powershell's "helpful" language.