# How do I set a default value for variable in Powershell with the value of another variable?

Tags: powershell

In bash I can do something like this to set `name` to a default value if `UserName` is not set:

```
name=${UserName:-James}
```

Does Powershell support something like this?

Comment: As a parameter or only as a variable?

Comment: This has a valid answer that is unrelated to the "duplicate" and works for all versions of powershell. The reason it is not a duplicate is because the correct answer is not a valid answer to the duplicate. 

`$var = Get-VAriable -Name Foo -ValueOnly -scope Global -ea SilentlyContinue || "default_value"`
gets the job done.  This question should be reopened as it is the best existing question to post this solution to.

Answer (score 2):

Using functions and parameters we can do something like what I believe you are doing.

A function example:

```
function WriteUser
{
    param($user = "A User",
    $message = "Message")
    Write-Host $user
    Write-Host $message
}
```

calling the function without parameters

```
WriteUser
```

will give you the output:

> A User
>
> Message

WriteUser -user "Me" -message "Error"

would write the following:

> Me
>
> Error

A couple extra notes, you do not have to use the parameter names.

```
WriteUser "Bob" "All Systems Go" would work by the order of the parameters.
```

You can switch the order of the named parameters as well:

```
WriteUser -message "Error" -user "user, user"
```

and the function will put the to the correct parameter.

Otherwise, I believe you would have to do something to approximate ternary behavior like:

```
function Like-Tern
{
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt $args.Count; $i++)
    {
        if ($args[$i] -eq ":")
        {
            $coord = $i
            break
        }
    }
    
    if ($coord -eq 0) { throw new System.Exception "No operator!" }
    $toReturn
    if ($args[$coord - 1] -eq "")
    {
        $toReturn = $args[$coord + 1]
    }
    else 
    {
        $toReturn = $args[$coord -1]
    }
    
    return $toReturn
}
```

[Credit for the idea here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341998/ternary-operator-in-powershell)
A function file could also include:

```
Set-Alias ~ Like-Tern -Option AllScope
```

And then you would use it like:

```
$var = ~ $Value : "Johnny"
```

Of course, `~` was completely arbitrary because I couldn't get `${` to work...

Comment: Further evidence that the designers of PowerShell had no idea what they were doing..

Comment: Please beware that "~" refers by default to the home directory, as in Unix shells.

Comment: @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo 3 years ago, I wouldn't have really considered that at all! But with PowerShell becoming more of a thing on Linux that is a very good call out.