# Failed PowerShell ValidateSet -- Error Action to set variable to default?

Tags: powershell, validateset

```
function foo
{
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateSet('Test1','Test2','Test3')] 
        [String]$ChooseOne= 'Test1',
    )

do xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
{

foo -ChooseOne Test9
```

I'm working on a powershell function with a set of required parameters. The validate set works great, however as Validate Set is.. if an option is entered that is not one of the listed options.. I'll get an error like below:

```
foo: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ChooseOne'. The argument "Test9" does not belong to the set "Test1,Test2,Test3" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the 
command again.
At line:1 char:1
+ foo
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [foo], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,foo
```

**Is there a way to have an error action to set the wronged variable to it's default that was previously defined?**

So in this case it would default `$ChooseOne` to "`Test1`"

Comment: There are plenty of advanced function examples that use parameters and their various options. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154887/set-a-default-value-for-variable-in-powershell and also [reference TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15994.powershell-advanced-function-parameter-attributes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In your *question* **you explicitly pass an *invalid* argument to your validation set-constrained `-ChooseOne` parameter**, and then ask:

> Is there a way to have an error action to set the wronged variable to its default that was previously defined?

The answer is: **no, and for a good reason**: if you define your parameter to only accept an argument from a defined set of acceptable values, you expressly want to *prevent* passing an *unacceptable* value, so you *want* PowerShell to report an error.

**If you want to accept invalid values but quietly ignore them - which seems like a bad idea** - *do not use a validation attribute* on the parameter and instead handle the validation - and quiet reversion to a default value - in your function *body*.

As an aside: **There is no point in defining a *default value* for a parameter that is marked as *mandatory*.**

---

**In your own [*answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42332503/45375) you're *changing the premise* of your question** to **not passing *any* value** to your `-ChooseOne` parameter.

Making a parameter *not* mandatory, i.e., *optional* - which is the *default*, so no explicit `[parameter(Mandatory=$false)]` is needed  - indeed makes any default value declared for it take effect if no argument is passed.

Comment: Note: I believe this answer to be correct and - hopefully - helpful. If you disagree, please tell us _why_, and I'm happy to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

If I make the value not mandatory, it'll be able to use its default as wanted.

```
[parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
```