# Elegant way of setting default value for variable in Powershell 6.0?

Tags: powershell, powershell-6.0

I have the following, which works but looks clunky:

```
if($config.contentDir){ 
    $contentDir = $config.contentDir
} else { 
    $contentDir = "contents"
}
```

Is there a nicer way of doing this? I have seen this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154887/set-a-default-value-for-variable-in-powershell?answertab=votes#tab-top), but it isn't exactly "nicer". Just wondering if 6.0 brought any improvements?

I'm likely to be handling a large amount of config options, so it's going to get fairly messy.

Comment: I'd note (and cry a little from no upvotes there): With the boilerplate code out of the way `$contentDir = ~ $config.contentDir : "contents" could over enough uses be much nicer. That said, until a true ternary operator comes out, everything is a mix of hacks or more verbose code like @Bill_Stewart showed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little shorter...

```
$contentDir = if ( $config.contentDir ) { $config.contentDir } else { "contents" }
```

You could also define an `iif` function:

```
function iif {
  param(
    [ScriptBlock] $testExpr,
    [ScriptBlock] $trueExpr,
    [ScriptBlock] $falseExpr
  )
  if ( & $testExpr ) {
    & $trueExpr
  }
  else {
    & $falseExpr
  }
}
```

Then you could shorten to this:

```
$contentDir = iif { $config.contentDir } { $config.contentDir } { "contents" }
```

As an aside, it looks like the next version of PowerShell will support the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) (see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-7-preview-4/), so in the future, you'll be able to write something like:

```
$contentDir = $config.contentDir ? $config.contentDir : "contents"
```

Comment: Thanks - given what I'm working on and my newbieness, I imagine we'll have 7.0 long before I'm done.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**:

- [*Null-coalescing operators*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#null-coalescing-operator-) were introduced in PowerShell (Core) **7.0** (along with a [*ternary operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false)), which enables the following **v7+ solution**:

  ```
  $contentDir = $config.contentDir ?? 'content'
  ```

---

**PowerShell v6- solutions**:

What you'e looking for is **[null-coalescing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator)**, which PowerShell doesn't have as of v7.0.0-preview.4.

For now, this will have to do:

```
$contentDir = if ($null -eq $config.contentDir) { 'content' } else { $config.contentDir }
```

<sup>Note: `$null` is deliberately placed on the LHS of `-eq` to unambiguously test for `$null`, because as the RHS it would act as a *filter* if the value to test happens to be *array*-valued.</sup>

An adaptation of [Lee Daily's array-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070396/45375) enables a **more concise** solution:

```
$contentDir = ($config.ContentDir, 'content')[$null -eq $config.ContentDir]
```

Use of the [ternary operator (conditional)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:), which will be implemented in v7.0, enables a **similarly concise** equivalent:

```
$contentDir = $null -eq $config.contentDir ? 'content' : $config.contentDir
```

However, all these approaches have the following **undesirable aspects**:

- They require an explicit reference to `$null`; note that `if ($config.ContentDir)` - i.e. coercing the value to a Boolean - may work with *strings*, but is not generally robust, because non-`$null` values such as `0` can evaluate to `$false` too.
- `$config.contentDir`, the value to test for `$null`, must be accessed *twice*, which can have side effects.

---

Defining a **custom function** named, say, `??`, can address these problems:

```
# Custom function that emulates null-coalescing.
function ?? ($PossiblyNull, $ValueIfNull) { 
  if ($null -eq $PossiblyNull) { $ValueIfNull } else { $PossiblyNull }
}

$contentDir = ?? $config.contentDir 'content'
```

However, such a custom function has **down-sides**:

The **down-sides of custom functions** are:

- You need to **include or import them** into in every piece of code you want to use them in.
- If you choose familiar name such as `??`, the **placement of operands can get confusing**, because you must (invariably) place them differently in PowerShell, given the implementation as a *function* (e.g., `a ?? b` in C# vs. `?? $a $b` in PowerShell) - especially once true null-coalescing gets implemented in PowerShell: see next section.
- And, of course, calling a function adds overhead.

---

If [this GitHub feature request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3240) is implemented, you'll be able to use **true null-coalescing**, which is both the **most concise** solution and **avoids the aforementioned undesirable aspects**:

```
# Hopefully soon
$contentDir = $config.contentDir ?? 'content'
```

A related feature also proposed in the linked GitHub issue is *null-conditional assignment*, `$config.ContentDir ?= 'content'`

Answer (score 2):

as `Bill_Stewart` showed, there is a ternary operator due in ps7. however, you can get something similar by using a two-item array and taking advantage of how PoSh will coerce values -- `$False` gives `0`, `$True` gives `1`.

```
$Config = [PSCustomObject]@{
    ContentDir = 'SomewhereElse'
    }
#$Config.ContentDir = ''

$ContentDir = @('contents', $Config.ContentDir)[[bool]$Config.ContentDir]

$ContentDir
```

output with line 4 commented out = `SomewhereElse`
output with line 4 enabled = `contents`

Comment: The array workaround is interesting but IMO too arcane.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - yep, it is a tad off-the-wall ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Sort of like '||' in bash.  If the first one is false or null, it will do the second one.

```
[void](($contentDir = $config.contentDir) -or ($contentDir = "contents"))
```