# PowerShell ternary and default operator

Tags: powershell, ternary-operator, conditional-operator, scriptblock

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33672033/190281) answer I tried to create another operator (alias) that reuses that ternary one, and I get error when executing the command:

> The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name , a script block, or a CommandInfo object.

The error is raised on the line when a value from ternary operator is being returned. I'm pretty much stuck with it and I don't understand why this happens.

The code:

```
Function Invoke-Ternary {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [scriptblock]$Condition, 
        [scriptblock]$TrueBlock, 
        [scriptblock]$FalseBlock
    )

    Process {
        if (&$Condition) {
            return &$TrueBlock
        }

        return &$FalseBlock
    }
}

Function Get-ValueOrDefault {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [scriptblock]$Value,
        [scriptblock]$DefaultValue
    )

    Process {
        Invoke-Ternary $Value $Value $DefaultValue
    }
}

Set-Alias ?: Invoke-Ternary -Description "PS ternary operator workaround"
Set-Alias ?? Invoke-Ternary -Description "PS default value operator workaround"
```

Usage:

This works fine:

```
?: { $non_existing_variable } { $non_existing_variable } {'default'}
```

This throws the error mentioned above:

```
??  { $non_existing_variable } { 'default' }
```

Comment: `Set-Alias ?? Invoke-Ternary` -> `Set-Alias ?? Get-ValueOrDefault`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers OMG, I can't believe I missed that. I feel so stupid right now :( I'm going to leave the question though, maybe it's gonna' be of any use for somebody else and as a painful reminder for me. I've been on it for couple of hours :)

Answer (score 1):

I've recently improved (open PullRequest) the ternary conditional and null-coalescing operators in the PoweShell lib 'Pscx'
Pls have a look for my solution.

**My github topic branch:** [UtilityModule_Invoke-Operators](https://github.com/madmidi/Pscx/blob/UtilityModule_Invoke-Operators/Src/Pscx/Modules/Utility/Pscx.Utility.psm1)

#### Functions:

```
Invoke-Ternary
Invoke-TernaryAsPipe
Invoke-NullCoalescing
NullCoalescingAsPipe
```

#### Aliases

```
Set-Alias :?:   Pscx\Invoke-Ternary                     -Description "PSCX alias"
Set-Alias ?:    Pscx\Invoke-TernaryAsPipe               -Description "PSCX alias"
Set-Alias :??   Pscx\Invoke-NullCoalescing              -Description "PSCX alias"
Set-Alias ??    Pscx\Invoke-NullCoalescingAsPipe        -Description "PSCX alias"
```

#### Usage

```
<condition_expression> |?: <true_expression> <false_expression>

<variable_expression> |?? <alternate_expression>
```

As expression you can pass:
            $null, a literal, a variable, an 'external' expression ($b -eq 4) or a scriptblock {$b -eq 4}


If a variable in the variable expression is $null or not existing, the alternate expression is evaluated as output.