# Why isn't the Ternary Operator in Powershell assigning my value?

Tags: powershell, conditional-operator

So I have the following powershell script...using the [ternary operator of Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341998/ternary-operator-in-powershell) and I'm starting to doubt it's power:

```
PS> $dasName="vCs01"

PS> $specialSubDerr @{
    "VCS01"="Derr";
    "VSC02"="dir";
    }

PS> $subDerr = @({"default"},{"$($specialSubDerr[$dasName.ToUpper()])"})[$specialSubDerr.contains($dasName.ToUpper())]
PS> $subDerr
"$($specialSubDerr[$dasName])"

PS> $($specialSubDerr[$dasName.ToUpper()])
Derr
```

So in the last 2 lines executed, why isn't the value assigned to `$subDerr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> using the ternary operator of Powershell

**Your code does *not* use PowerShell's ternary operator, which is available only in v7.0+**; instead it uses a *suboptimal emulation* that combines a 2-element array with a conditional whose Boolean result is mapped onto array index `0` (for `$false`) or `1` (for `$true`).
Aside from not being *conceptually obvious*, the workaround is suboptimal in that it *doesn't short-circuit* the evaluation of the alternatives; that is, *both* elements of the array are *unconditionally* evaluated before one is chosen.

Note:

- **You don't need `@(...)` for array literals** - it is inefficient in PowerShell versions up to 5.0, but, more importantly, it invites conceptual confusion by falsely suggesting that it *constructs* arrays - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091504/45375).
- **Don't use `$(...)` for single commands or expressions**, *except* inside *expandable strings* (`"..."`) and/or if you need to embed *multiple* statements in another statement.
- **PowerShell is case-*insensitive* by default**, so there is *no* need to case-normalize the keys of hashtable entries with `.ToUpper()`.
- **`{...}` defines a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)**, which is a *reusable piece of PowerShell code* that you can execute on demand *later*, typically via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-); by itself, a script block *prints* as its *stringified value*, which is the *literal contents* between the opening `{` and the closing `}`; **do *not* use script blocks as-is if you want to output *values***.

---

In **PowerShell [Core] 7.0+**, you can use the **null-coalescing operator `??`** to get what you want:

```
$subDerr = $specialSubDerr[$dasName] ?? 'default'
```

<sup>Note: Strictly speaking, the above also selects `'default'` if an entry with key `$dasName` *exists*, but *happens to be have value `$null`*.</sup>

Alternatively, **using the ternary conditional**:

```
$subDerr = $specialSubDerr.Contains($dasName) ? $specialSubDerr[$dasName] : 'default'
```

---

In **earlier versions**, using the ***emulation* of a ternary conditional** (the fixed version of what you tried):

```
$subDerr = ('default', $specialSubDerr[$dasName])[$specialSubDerr.Contains($dasName)]
```

or, more explicitly (*with* short-circuiting):

```
$subDerr = if ($specialSubDerr.Contains($dasName)) { $specialSubDerr[$dasName] }
           else                                    { 'default' }
```