# PowerShell empty array initialization fails in conditional variable assignment

Tags: arrays, powershell

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341998/ternary-operator-in-powershell) about how to best create a (ternary operator)-ish expression in PowerShell, I've tried to convert this:

```
if ($condition)
{ 
   $accessList = @() 
}
else
{
    $accessList = $accessControl.AllowedItems
}
```

into this:

```
$accessList = if ($condition) { @() } else { $accessControl.AllowedItems }
```

The one-liner fails to initialize an empty array. The resulting `$accessList` doesn't have any array properties/methods and `$NULL -eq $accessList` returns *True*. This version doesn't work either:

```
$accessList = $(if ($condition) { @() } else { $accessControl.AllowedItems })
```

Oddly enough, if I attempt to initialize a non-empty array, the one-liner works. It probably has something to do with variable evaluation and how the pipeline works, but after googling for a bit, I've found no detailed explanation of this particluar case. Please help understand the mechanics behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to prevent the implicit *enumeration* of your empty array in the (implicitly used) pipeline, the simplest solution to which is to wrap it in an aux., transitory array, which you can construct with the unary form of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-):

```
$accessList = if ($condition) { , @() } else { $accessControl.AllowedItems }
```

**PowerShell 7+** offers a way to *bypass* the problem, by using `?:`, the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false), which acts as an *expression* (see explanation below):

```
$accessList = $condition ? @() : $accessControl.AllowedItems
```

---

**Background information**:

The distinction is subtle:

In:

```
$accessList = @()
```

`@()` is an *expression* and therefore assigned as-is.

In:

```
$accessList = if ($condition) { @() }
```

`if ($condition) { @() }` is an entire *statement*, and as such its output  (`@()`) implicitly uses the *pipeline*, where an array is implicitly *enumerated* and its *elements* are sent to the pipeline; in the case of an *empty* array, there is nothing to enumerate, and therefore *nothing* is output ( which is technically represented as the `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` singleton).

Wrapping the array in an aux., transitory array as shown at the top makes the pipeline enumerate only that aux. array, so the wrapped array is output as a whole.

The same applies to outputs from *commands*, notably if you try to output an array *as a whole* from a script or function.

Generally, though, note that PowerShell commands are *not* expected to output *collections as a whole* and to instead enumerate them.

Also note that if *two or more* elements are enumerated in the pipeline and you assign the output to a variable, PowerShell implicitly collects them in an `[object[]]` array, whereas a *single* element is assigned as-is (no array wrapper). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/45375) for more information.