# Powershell 5.1 ternary with array assignment

Tags: powershell, conditional-operator, ternary

I have a question towards ternary operators in Powershell 5.1. It doesn't work as I expected it if I try to assign an array @(...):

```
    # I can assign an array to a variable:
    $a=@("TRUE")
    write-host "a:" $a
    
    # I can do that in a proper if/then statement, too:
    $b = @(if ($false) {@("True")} else {@("False")})
    write-host "b:" $b
    
    # Assignment of string constants works fine with ternary syntax:
    $c = @( {"True"} , {"False"} )[!$true]
    write-host "c:" $c
    
    # but not with array assignments:
    $d = @( {@("True")} , {@("False")} )[!$false]
    write-host "d:" $d
    # Expected: "False". 
    # Actual output: @("False")
```

**Output:**

```
a: TRUE
b: False
c: "True"
d: @("False")
```

A thread regarding ternary operators doesn't clarify this for me. ([Ternary operator in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341998))

**Update:** $d needs to be an array, as well as the two inner items. Here they were shown with just one string constant for simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:

- *PowerShell (Core) 7+* now has a *built-i*n ternary operator, so that you could use something like `$var = $true ? "True" : "False"`

---

Do not use `{ ... }` around your operands: **`{ ... }` is used for [*script-block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) literals**, which evaluate to their *verbatim content* (without the delimiters) in a *string context*.

Omitting the enclosing `{` and `}` solves the immediate problem:

```sh
$d = @( @("True") , @("False") )[!$false]
write-host "d:" $d
```

However, the use of `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) seems both redundant and ineffective, depending on your intent; the above is equivalent to:

```sh
$d = ( "True", "False" )[!$false]
write-host "d:" $d
```

<sup>Note that `@(...)` is never *required* for array *literals*; use of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), is generally sufficient. See the middle section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091504/45375) for more information.</sup>

If you want `$d` to be an *array*, you need to apply `@(...)` to the *entire* expression:

```sh
# $d is now a 1-element array containing 'False'
$d = @(( "True", "False" )[!$false])
write-host "d:" $d
```

Alternatively, *type-constrain* `$d` to be an array:

```sh
# $d is now a 1-element array containing 'False'
[array] $d = ( "True", "False" )[!$false]
write-host "d:" $d
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The concret application was to eliminate element number x from array $a by joining the preceeding and succeeding parts:
$LastElement = $a.GetUpperBound(0); if ($LastElement -ge 0) {
$a = @(@(@(),@($a[0..($x-1)]))[$x -ne 0]; @(@(), @($a[($x+1)..$LastElement]))[$x -ne $LastElement]) }