# Regex capture multi matches in Group

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm not sure if this is possible. I'am searching for a way to capture multiple matches in a group.

This it work perfectly fine:

```
"Catch me if you can" -match "(?=.*(Catch))"
Result: Catch
```

I would like to have the result of two matches in the group:

```
"Catch me if you can" -match "(?=.*Catch)(?=.*me)"
Expected Result: Catch me
```

Comment: Sounds like a solution can be like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48300324/3832970). `$res = switch ( "Catch me if you can" -match "(?=.*Catch)(?=.*me)" ) { $true {"Catch me"} $false {""} }`. At any rate, it is impossible to get capturing groups concatenated themselves, you will need to capture and concatenate them once there is a match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I later realized that there's no need for `switch`: a `-match` solution that doesn't hard-code the results _is_ possible, given that only a _single_ match is required: `if ('Catch me if you can' -match '(?=.*(Catch))(?=.*(me))') { $Matches[1..2] -join ' ' }` However, more work is needed if the captures should be reported in _input order_.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note: If *hard-coding* the result of both regex subexpressions matching is sufficient, simply use:

`if ('Catch me if you can' -match '(?=.*Catch)(?=.*me)') { 'Catch me' }`</sup>

You're trying to:

- match *two* separate regex subexpressions,
- and report what specific strings they matched *only if BOTH matched*.

Note:

- While it is possible to use a variation of your regex, which concatenates two *look-ahead assertions* (`(?=.*(Catch))(?=.*(me))`), to extract what the two subexpressions of interest captured, the captured substrings would be reported in the order in which the subexpressions are specified *in the regex*, not in the order in which the substrings appear *in the input string*. E.g., input string `'me Catch if you can'` would also result in output string `'Catch me'`
- The following solution uses the [`[regex]::Match()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match) .NET API for **preserving the input order of the captured substrings** by sorting the captures by their starting position in the input string:

```sh
$match = [regex]::Match('me Catch if you can', '(?=.*(Catch))(?=.*(me))', 'IgnoreCase')
if ($match.Success) { ($match.Groups | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Sort-Object Position).Value -join ' ' }
```

<sup>Note the use of the `IgnoreCase` option, so as to match PowerShell's default behavior of case-*insensitive* matching.</sup>

The above outputs `'me Catch'`, i.e. the captured substrings in the order in which they appear in the input string.

**If instead you prefer that the captured substrings be reported in the order in which the subexpressions that matched them appear *in the regex*** (`'Catch me'`), simply omit `| Sort-Object Position` from the command above.

Alternatively, you then could make your [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operation work, as follows, by enclosing the subexpressions of interest in `(...)` to form *capture groups* and then accessing the captured substrings via the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) - but note that *no* information about matching *positions* is then available:

```sh
if ('me Catch if you can' -match '(?=.*(Catch))(?=.*(me))') {
  $Matches[1..2] -join ' '  # -> 'Catch me'
}
```

Note that this only works because a *single* match result captures *both* substrings of interest, due to the concatenation of two look-ahead assertions (`(?=...)`);  because `-match` only ever looks for *one* match, the simpler `'Catch|me'` regex would *not* work, as it would stop matching once *either* subexpression is found.

See also:

- [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867), which  suggests introducing a `-matchall` operator that returns *all* matches found in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

The (?= is a LookAhead, but you don't have it looking ahead of anything. In this example LookAhead is looking ahead of "Catch" to see if it can find ".*me".

```
Catch(?=.*me)
```

Also, do you really want to match "catchABCme"?  I would think you would want to match "catch ABC me", but not "catchABCme", "catchABC me", or "catch ABCme".

Here is some test code to play with:

```
$Lines = @(
    'catch ABC me if you can',
    'catch ABCme if you can',
    'catchABC me if you can'
)
$RegExCheckers = @(
    'Catch(?=.*me)',
    'Catch(?=.*\s+me)',
    'Catch\s(?=(.*\s+)?me)'
)

foreach ($RegEx in $RegExCheckers) {
    $RegExOut = "`"$RegEx`"".PadLeft(22,' ')
    foreach ($Line in $Lines) {
        $LineOut = "`"$Line`"".PadLeft(26,' ')
        if($Line -match $RegEx) {
            Write-Host "$RegExOut        matches $LineOut"
        } else {
            Write-Host "$RegExOut didn't match   $LineOut"
        }
    }
    Write-Host
}
```

And here is the output:

```
        "Catch(?=.*me)"        matches  "catch ABC me if you can"
        "Catch(?=.*me)"        matches   "catch ABCme if you can"
        "Catch(?=.*me)"        matches   "catchABC me if you can"

     "Catch(?=.*\s+me)"        matches  "catch ABC me if you can"
     "Catch(?=.*\s+me)" didn't match     "catch ABCme if you can"
     "Catch(?=.*\s+me)"        matches   "catchABC me if you can"

"Catch\s(?=(.*\s+)?me)"        matches  "catch ABC me if you can"
"Catch\s(?=(.*\s+)?me)" didn't match     "catch ABCme if you can"
"Catch\s(?=(.*\s+)?me)" didn't match     "catchABC me if you can"
```

As you can see, the last RegEx expression requires a space after "catch" and before "me".

Also, a great place to test RegEx is [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), you can place the RegEx at the top and multiple lines you want to test it against in the box in the middle.